# ITunes doesnt seem to expose COM interfaces for its new Movement and Work fields

Tags: com, itunes, com4j

I use **Com4j** to let my Java app comunicate with **iTunes on Windows**, I saw that my generated classes dont contain methods to let me update *movement* and *work* fields like I can update other fields such as *artist* or *album*.

So I regenned the classes using

```
  c:\Code\jthink\opensrc\com4j-20120426-2>java -jar tlbimp.jar -o C:\Code\jthink\SongKong\src\main\java -p com.jthink.songkong.itunes  "C:\Program Files\iTunes\iTunes.exe"
```

against the latest 12.6 iTunes exe and they still arent here. (I would expect them in IITFileOrCDTrack.java) am I doing something wrong or does this mean that iTunes have to explicity code to expose there new fields and they have decided not to.

So does that mean iTunes has to explicity code a new COM interface to make these fields accessible to other programs

Note these new fields are available via applescript on a Mac machine

Comment: Repeatedly adding bounties to this question is not going to get Apple programmers off their duff.  You can use the OleView.exe sdk utility (File > View Typelib) to see what you can expect.  The type library version number is 1.13, not an encouraging number for a 2.x program version. And you won't find anything related to "movement" or "work" back in version 12.6, other than the Grouping property.   File a bug report and you might get somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant - wasnt actual;ly aware you could file bugs against Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in above [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43725086/itunes-doesnt-seem-to-expose-com-interfaces-for-its-new-movement-and-work-fields#comment75375799_43725086) you basically have two options:

1. File a bug with Apple and wait (possibly indefinitely)
2. Use the `grouping` field instead

Personally, I have found the `grouping` field to accomplish the role of 'subcategory'. While I realize it is less ideal than having the ability to utilize both `movement` and `work` fields, I have been able to accomplish my desired functionality via `grouping` thus far.

Comment: I need to write work and movement, but to shame wasting it Ill give you the bounty for suggesting fileing a bug report